# multiple exclude data can't catch in filter option odata

Tags: odata, sapui5, abap

I create smart table sapui5 screen by using odata (S4Hana) .

On the odata side, get the filter value from smart filter by using this method ⇒ [ io_tech_request_context->get_filter( )->get_filter_select_options( ).]

It is ok when I pass the filter value as multiple Include option .

[image: OK]

When I pass the filter value as multiple Exclude option , the data can't access from filter_select option method. The data can be get in filter_string method but it is difficult to get the data and put to range table .
[image: NG]

Let me know how to get the filter value from entity set of odata .

Answer (score 0):

> Let me know how to get the filter value from entity set of odata .

There are defined [rules](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1671893), how your **$filter** parameter has to look like to get converted into the  import parameter **it_filter_select_options**. If you breach this rules (you did...) the import parameter **it_filter_select_options** will be empty.

Sadly, there's no *simple solution*.

If you need to convert the parameter **iv_filter_string** into **select options** there are quite a few Tutorials/Blogs about it.

- [Filter String How To](https://mysapgw.wordpress.com/2012/01/25/filter-string-how-to/)
- [How to Parse IV_FILTER_STRING in GET_ENTITYSET](https://answers.sap.com/questions/487793/how-to-parse-ivfilterstring-in-getentityset.html)